# JQuery how to get closest value to a radio button

Tags: jquery

```
<div style="float:left; width:48%;">
 <input type="radio" value="archive.png" name="main_link">
 <img width="32px" height="32px" src="/images/Frontpage/ref_archive.png">

</div>
```

I have an html hierarchy like this and the div blocks are repeating . I wont to know a way to get the img src value , so far i have tried

```
  $("input[type='radio']").live("click", function () {
            /*******************************************************/
            var element = $(this);

            alert(element.closest("div").find("img").attr("src"));
  });
```

Comment: This would work without issues.!

Comment: this wont work gives blank

Comment: Yes and it does !  http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/u8yf3/  `live` is a method that is not available in later versions of jQuery.  Check the documentation.

Comment: @Kirov If it is not working then you must be using latest version of jquery which doesn;t support `.live()`

Comment: well its working on the fiddle um not having the latest version

Answer (score 1):

you can get it also with

```
alert(element.parent().find("img").attr("src"));
```

Comment: then I do not understand the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `.on()` method.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

From the jQuery website:
"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function () {
            var element = $(this);
            alert(element.closest("div").find("img").attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: @Kalanamith Just a followup as I see there was never a selected answer. Did you have any further questions? Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I thought your jquery doesn't support live method instead of this use on method

```
$(document).on("click","input[type='radio']", function () {

            var element = $(this);

            alert(element.closest("div").find("img").attr("src"));
  });
```